# Start Azure VM and login to Windows 10 automatically

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine

I have a program that I would like to run daily on Azure.  Is it possible to start up the VM and login to windows 10 automatically?   I have scheduled the VM to start up and shut down, but I have not found a way to login to windows yet.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try [these methods](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-automatically-login-in-windows-10/) like Autologon

Comment: Also is [this case](https://serverfault.com/questions/583517/start-program-on-computer-startup-when-nobody-is-logged-on-and-show-the-window-w) helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Run this to get vm autologin configured (i did it during deployment via Powershell extension)

```
$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoAdminLogon" -Value "1" -type String 
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultUsername" -Value "$username" -type String 
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultPassword" -Value "$password" -type String
```

Comment: where am I supposed to run this script?

Comment: @Amit Raz, Powershell I believe.

Comment: Same can be performed manually in `Registry Editor`

Comment: On searching for an answer to the above question.  I find this answer that may be helpful, though I have no firm idea, because it is so insufficient.  If it could be expanded on with more detail perhaps.  Thanks.